Application of Reciprocal Currency Rates and Triangular Arbitrage in FX Trading
After nearly a decade as a software engineer in finance, I find myself grappling with a question about FX trading that I've always hesitated to ask, particularly concerning the calculation of reciprocal currency rates and the use of indirect methods such as triangular arbitrage.
I am currently managing the FX component of a trading system and Iam keen to explore the accuracy and reliability of using reciprocal rates, especially for less liquid currency pairs. Common practice holds that for liquid currencies, the reciprocal of GBPUSD (i.e., USDGBP) should closely approximate 1/GBPUSD, an assumption that aligns with the Efficient Market Hypothesis, which posits that markets quickly correct such discrepancies.
Questions:
Extension to Illiquid Pairs: While it is broadly accepted that the reciprocal of a highly liquid currency pair like GBPUSD is a fair approximation for USDGBP, can this method be extended safely to less liquid pairs such as ZARSEK without introducing non negligible market risk?
In tasks like portfolio P&L analysis and attribution, is it prudent to mechanically calculate reciprocals for all currency pairs? What are the potential risks or pitfalls, especially with illiquid pairs known for wider spreads and higher volatility?
Considering the operational subscription costs associated with currency price updates, how safe is it to subscribe only to USDXXX currencies and infer non-USD denominated currencies using a triangular approach? Could this practice introduce a "model" risk into our operations?
I hope my questions do not come across as too trivial. While they are operational in nature, I believe there's an element of "model" risk involved.
Thank you in advance for your insights!

Apologies, I'm trying to understand the question - isn't this just bid-offer spread?

Perhaps I didn't explain myself clearly. Let me try to be more pragmatic. If you subscribe to an FX provider for market data for a non-G10 currency pair that is less liquid and efficient than major pairs like GBPUSD or EURUSD, consider this scenario: Say you need to be able to price contracts denominated in both ZARSEK and SEKZAR. Does it make sense to subscribe to only one symbol and calculate the other as a reciprocal (1/X), or, given that the FX market may not be very efficient in the short term for such pairs, would it be more prudent to subscribe to both of them?

Thanks I think I understand the question better, and from purely IT/data governance point of view, I would subscribe to both sides, rather than assume than one side is reciprocal of the other, in other to replicate rounding done by the provider. E.g. if 1 $c_1$ equals 3 of $c_2$, then 1 $c_2 = \frac{1}{3}c_1$, but in the data feed, it could be 0.333 or 0.3333 or 0.33334 etc - you want to be as close as possible to what others what use capturing all the decimals. And if the other side is unavailable and you do compute it, then remember its "provenance" and "lineage".
